# knitting with R to PDF

Tags: r, rstudio, miktex

I continiously get the following error when ı try to knit RMD file to pdf.

"incomplete final row has been found.
I downloaded miktex, and downloaded all the updates. what is the issue, any idea?

here is the link for RDS file:
https://github.com/MEF-BDA503/pj18-gokceezeroglu/blob/master/ranking2017.rds

here is the link for example RMD file:
https://github.com/MEF-BDA503/pj18-gokceezeroglu/blob/master/example.Rmd

Comment: Can you get it to knit to a .html?

Comment: yes I can, but ı need R markdown generated pdf document.

Comment: I was just asking because that might help to diagnose what's going on. I think, though, that this will be hard to do unless you can post a reproducible example. Can you post enough of the .Rmd so that I can replicate the failure to compile to pdf? If you look at the log, does it indicate where the problem is occurring?

Comment: How can ı reach log file?and more importantly how can I interpret the error over log file?  read_log( "access.log", skip=0, col_names=FALSE ) is not working for R 3.5.1

Comment: If you're using R Studio, the console should have a tab called log right after you try to compile. Beyond that, I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: For converting  R-markdown document to PDF, mikteks can  be used. The important point is downloading the correct version  of miktex. You have to download the full package for your pc.